# Can you specify route constraints in Rails using object mapping or lambdas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to do the following:

```
constraints( brand: "/#{Brand.all.map(&:name).join('|')}/" )
```

Unfortunately it does not seem to be working as expected. Is there any way to do this? Perhaps using a lambda?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely define your own complex constraints using a custom class. That class should respond to the `matches?` method, which takes `request` as the argument.

The rails documentation specifies this method in the **Advanced Constraints** section [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints).

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @31piy got me on the right track, but ultimately wasn't the complete answer. Here's the working code:

```
constraints( lambda { |request| Brand.pluck(:slug).include?(request.params["brand"]) } ) do
  collection do
    get ':brand/:release', to: 'releases#show', as: 'release'
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked for me, but made a slight change using: `Property.exists?(slug: request.params['slug'])`